# DTO can be considered as Business objects (with behavior)?

Tags: design-patterns, spring, domain-model, spring-mvc

Based on this Question and its answer :

[Object in Business layer same as DTO with logic?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/261264/object-in-business-layer-same-as-dto-with-logic)

I want to ask :

What if instead of DAL, I'm getting data from a remote service (API) through DTOs. My DTOs here represent prettymuch the business objects with all the relationships in between. Although there is BOs in the API that I'm calling I cannot put the behavior that I need there as it is specific for me. How can I deal with this ?

if no behavior on DTO so what ? This look crappy

**(API) <--DTO--> (mappingService) <--Domain object-->  (domainService)  <--DTO--> (UI)  ??**

Comment: Are you using an anemic or rich domain?

Comment: If your system doesn't need rich domain data models, because it's a mere proxy between UI and 3rd party services. Why do you care about the business? The schema you have suggested makes sense. Your system acts like a integration facade.

Answer (score 3):

There are several architectural patterns for your choice:

- The [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) is a distribution pattern and aims to transfer data between processes and remote services.  The goal is to reduce the number of [interprocess function/method calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx) that are inefficient when crossing the boundaries of a single process.
- The [domain model object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) leaves transfer and persistance to a data gateway or a mapper.
- The [active record](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) is a mix between both. It aims at encapsulating data access together with domain logic.

Basically, combining your DTO with domain logic looks pretty much like an active record. It's a viable solution if your domain model is simple and if the domain object is very close to the DTO.

However, be aware of its major drawbacks :

- you no longer benefit from the decoupling offered by the DTO.  A DTO isolates your internal domain model, from the back-end implementation, and let each of it evolve at its own pace.
- it's not really aligned with the clean design principle of [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

And attention: use it only if the domain model is simple.  It's not a good idea if one object is simple but the whole model would be rather complex, because active records raise a lot of issues if you'd need to combine it with unit of work, an identity map or other [patterns of enterprise application architecture](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/).